GSC Identified 404 Not Found Pages
Google Search Console identified more than a hundred 404 not found pages. I traced those
pages, verified them as well as manually visited and checked their referring pages. They were indeed not found including majority of these referring pages.
Note: This 404 issues were from the report of "All known pages" on GSC. I just recently submitted a sitemap and its status is good. These all known pages however have problems.
I am new to managing websites. I just recently got a job and I want the website free of issues if possible. Based from the answers I found on the Internet, I got to either 301 redirect them, return 410 or use removal tool feature by GSC.
I am not quite sure on what steps should I take. I don't know what would be the best solution for the problems.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Sometimes a 404 is the right response.
It's only a problem if it means internal links are broken, or good external links are pointing to an incorrect URL.
GSC tells you about every URL it is aware of on your site so that you can track down problems.  It isn't a list of things to fix.  When Google finds a URL on the web, it adds it to the index.  I could create a 404 on your site now by linking to any URL that doesn't exist.
Reviewing the 404s is the right thing to do, as you may find something like a URL update without a redirect that is causing a good backlink to fail.  However, lots of URLs Google knows of will be dodgy bot-generated backlinks and things that don't need fixing, such as deleted blog tags.
301 any good broken backlink and fix any broken internal links (a site crawler such as Xenu can help find them), but I can't see much point in using a 410 unless you want to be semantically correct.  Google de-index 410s a bit faster, but they handle 404s and 410s about the same.

It depends.

If the pages don't exist anymore then remove internal links to them.
If the pages used to exist and now have a different url, then redirect them.
If new versions of the pages do not exist, then ensure they return 410 and remove them from GSC.

